# Remove Div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a code in which I want to delete a div when its inner link("Delete") is clicked. I know this question might be repeating and I have tried so many methods but not working. I dont know what's the problem.

Here is my HTML Rendering Code:

```
<div id="ViewRows">
    <br>
    <div class="ViewRow"> NOS: FA Comment: finance
        <a class="deleteViewRow" href="#">Delete</a>
    <br>
    </div>
    <div class="ViewRow">
       NOS: TPA Comment: Assistance
       <a class="deleteViewRow" href="#">Delete</a>
       <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript Code for removal of that div.

```
$("a.deleteViewRow").live("click", function () {
   $(this).parents("div.ViewRow:first").remove();
   return false;
});
```

I also tried following javascript:

```
$("#ViewRows").on("click", "a.deleteViewRow", function () {
    $(this).closest("div.ViewRow").andSelf().remove();
    return false;
});
```

I have tried same code on another page. It is working but when I applied the same logic in another page. It's not working. I know you all are right but I dont know whats problem. In firebug it's not even going into the function.

Comment: The second should work fine, besides `.andSelf()` is superfluous.

Comment: @VisioN, I have tried same code on another page. It is working but when I applied the same logic in another page. It's not working. I know you all are right but I dont know whats problem. In firebug it's not even going into the function.

Comment: Are you including jQuery on both pages?

Comment: @ktm5124 No. I am not calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this simple yet efficient code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/L2CsH/

```
$("#ViewRows").on("click", "a.deleteViewRow", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: it's working on chrome but i didn't test it on other browsers so i guess it is not working on other browsers

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$("#ViewRows").on("click", "a.deleteViewRow", function (e) {
    // prevent browser from following link
    e.preventDefault();
    // ".andSelf()" can be skipped - once the parent div is removed, the link gets removed as well
    $(this).closest("div.ViewRow").remove();
});
```

Comment: It does work: http://jsbin.com/eqajiw/1/edit what is not working is probably something else on page - does your browser report any Javascript errors?

Comment: I don't think e.preventDefault() is necessary, since he has href="#". Although he should remove the href="#" attribute, as a best practice.

Comment: Does (on the same page when above script fails) other scripts (JS functions) work? If not maybe you've disabled Javascript for testing, or something?

Comment: @ktm5124 It's not necessary, but I consider it a good practice. Removing href attribute all-together may cause links to break.

Comment: @WTK, I have use jquery functions for menu and other stuff. they all are working fine.

Comment: Ok, so check your HTML structure (is it similar to what you've pasted in your question?); does class names in HTML and Javascript match? Does the script fire if you use "onclick" attribute on links?

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent default action of link. `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#ViewRows").on("click", "a.deleteViewRow", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("div.ViewRow").remove(); //.andSelf() is not needed here. 
    //return false;
});
```

Demo : [Remove Div  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNzku/)

Comment: Why? This does not explain the encountered error. At best, you'll fix a scroll issue when the anchor is selected. But it's not pertinent to the isseu at hand.